# Visual Studio android emulator is not displaying images

Tags: android, image, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-emulator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Training.InstagramPage">
  <ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0, 20, 0,  0"      />
  </ContentPage.Padding>
  <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Padding="20,0,0,0">
      <Label x:Name="lblTitle">nyc_photographer</Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <Image Source="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/nature/3/"/>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="20,0,0,0">
      <Button x:Name="btnLike" TextColor="#127ac7" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="Like"></Button>
      <Button x:Name="btnComment" TextColor="#127ac7" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text ="Comment"></Button>
      <Button x:Name="btnShare" TextColor="#127ac7" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="Share"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
    <BoxView Color="#f0f0f0" HeightRequest="1"></BoxView>
    <StackLayout Padding="20,0,20,0">
      <Label x:Name="lblTotalLikes"  FontAttributes="Bold">700 Likes</Label>
      <Label x:Name="lblDescription"  TextColor="Gray">This is a shot yesterday in Skanor, Sweden, When driving home, from a couple of days of work in Denmark</Label>
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

hi, in the code above the image is not displayed at all using the visual studio android emulator. it is working perfectly on the windows app.

This page was running perfectly but all of a sudden it stopped.
I tried to create a new project with the just an image tag but still the image was not displayed on the android emulator.

I repaired / uninstalled / installed the visual studio community 2015, but still not displayed.

I also deleted the hyper v  images, uninstalled than reinstalled the hyper v and still with no luck

I tried to also load the image using the code behind as the following:

```
img.Source = new UriImageSource
        {
            Uri = new Uri("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/city/1/"),
            CachingEnabled = false,
            CacheValidity = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)

        };
```

Still not showing !

Note: I can navigate to the image path from the emulator browser

I am using Windows 10 with visual studio community 2015.

Anyone facing the same issue? what is the solution ?

Update: I checked the debug output and i got the following:

```
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
01-29 05:26:05.129 D/Mono    ( 1510): [0xba853170] worker starting
01-29 05:26:05.629 W/        ( 1510): _wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x1f
[0:] Image Loading: Error getting stream for http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/nature/3/: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:179 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x004a7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:389 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00027] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:176 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00027] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:176 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Forms+AndroidPlatformServices+<GetStreamAsync>d__14.MoveNext () [0x0003e] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Forms.cs:363 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00027] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:176 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at Xamarin.Forms.UriImageSource+<GetStreamAsyncUnchecked>d__22.MoveNext () [0x00224] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\UriImageSource.cs:166 
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #8
01-29 05:26:26.768 D/Mono    ( 1510): [0xb9f4da10] worker finishing
The thread 'Unknown' (0x8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Did you check the output window? Android sometimes puts stuff in there without actually breaking. For instance if the image is too big or something.

Comment: I made a basic demo but didn't reproduce your problem. Have you checked if your emulator has access to the internet?

Comment: Seems the problem is with virtual switch, when i am connected thru wifi the image is not displayed. but once i got wired connection the problem is gone.

Comment: Thanks Gerald and Elvis for your help.